# How can I access the __reactEventHandlers property of the DOM object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I am trying to access the '**__reactEventHandlers**' properties in JS. But I am not able to access the attribute in JS.But in developer console I can able see the attribute and i can able to access as well. Kindly help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the below mentioned way we can able to access the _reactEventHandler object form the DOM Object.

```
var abc=document.querySelector('._2LpG3');
var reactHandlerKey=Object.keys(abc).filter(function(item){
   return item.indexOf('__reactEventHandlers')>=0
});
var reactHandler=abc[reactHandlerKey[0]];
console.log(reactHandler) // React Event handler object and Properties
```

Thanks,

Hariharan S

Comment: This is super useful for triggering a React onChange() event that ignores dispatchEvent(). My one-liner solution: `ELEM[Object.keys(ELEM).filter(function(K){return K.indexOf('__reactEventHandlers')==0})[0]].onChange();` inspired by this answer. Thank you

Comment: this is exactly what i needed. I couldnt find anything about how the React events work internally, but they seem to have been scoped separately to not overlap with native events. So a `obj.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown'));` didnt do anything. The code above allowed me to call the handler manually.